# Jquery animation to extend table cell contents

Tags: jquery, animation, razor, jquery-animate

On a Razor page I have a long comment that I want to chop off. Then, I want to show the full comment at a prompt from the user.

On the page I have a for loop with the following:

```
<td>
    @if (Model.ApprovedFacilities[i].Comment.Length > 100)
    {
        var comment = Model.ApprovedFacilities[i].Comment;
        <span id="DisplaySpan_@i">@comment.Substring(0, 100)...</span>
        <span style="display:none" id="InitialSpan_@i">@comment.Substring(0, 100)...</span>
        <span style="display:none" id="NextSpan_@i">@comment</span>
        <a id="@i" class="showbutton">Show</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <label>@Model.ApprovedFacilities[i].Comment</label>
    }
</td>
```

What I'm having trouble with is setting up the jquery animation to have a smooth slide down/up effect. At present my jquery looks like this:

```
$(".showbutton").click(function () {

    var i = $(this).prop('id');
    if ($(this).html() == 'Show') {
        $("#DisplaySpan_" + i).animate({
            //'opacity': 0,
            'height': 'toggle'
        }, 400, function () {
            $(this).html($("#NextSpan_" + i).html()).animate({
                //'opacity': 1,
                'height': 'toggle'
            }, 400);
        });
        $(this).html("Hide");
    } else {
        $("#DisplaySpan_" + i).animate({
            //'opacity': 0,
            'height': 'toggle'
        }, 400, function () {
            $(this).html($("#InitialSpan_" + i).html()).animate({
                //'opacity': 1,
                'height': 'toggle'
            }, 400);
        });
        $(this).html("Show");
    }
});
```

What this causes is on the click of the button (anchor tag right now) the height of the element go's to zero, before going to the extended height. I demonstrated this behavior in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ps7zw4yg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ps7zw4yg/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".showbutton").click(function () {
            var i = $(this).prop('id');
            if ($(this).html() == 'Show') {
                var h = $("#NextSpan_" + i).height() + 80;
                $("#DisplaySpan_" + i).animate({
                    'height': h + 'px'
                }, 2000, 'linear');
                $("#DisplaySpan_" + i).html($("#NextSpan_" + i).html());
                $(this).html("Hide");
            } else {
                var h = $("#InitialSpan_" + i).height();
                $("#DisplaySpan_" + i).animate({
                    'height': h + 'px'
                }, 2000, 'linear', function(){
                    $("#DisplaySpan_" + i).html($("#InitialSpan_" + i).html());
                });
                $(this).html("Show");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```